# Dynamic use of Azure SQL Pool SKU family in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-sql-database

I am describing creating an Azure SQL Pool for via Terraform. On one environment I have a standard pool on another vcore.

the main difference in the section

```
sku {
    capacity = var.capacity_sql_pool_dtu
    name = var.capacity_sql_pool_sku_name
    tier = var.capacity_sql_pool_tier
    family  = var.capacity_sql_pool_family
  }
```

The family value is not used for the standard pool, how can I, depending on the environment, use or not use it so that my script does not crash with an error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to create a ***Dynamic sku block*** as per your environment i.e. ***`DTU`*** or ***`vcore`***. You can use the ***below code*** where in a ***variable you will be declaring sku tier and capacity*** and ***in the local blocks we will be validating your requirement*** and then ***using it in the elastic pool resource block***.

**Code:**

***Main.tf***

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}
locals {
  vcore_tiers                 = ["GeneralPurpose", "BusinessCritical"]
  elastic_pool_vcore_family   = "Gen5"
  elastic_pool_vcore_sku_name = var.sku != null ? format("%s_%s", var.sku.tier == "GeneralPurpose" ? "GP" : "BC", local.elastic_pool_vcore_family) : null
  elastic_pool_dtu_sku_name   = var.sku != null ? format("%sPool", var.sku.tier) : null
  elastic_pool_sku = var.sku != null ? {
    name     = contains(local.vcore_tiers, var.sku.tier) ? local.elastic_pool_vcore_sku_name : local.elastic_pool_dtu_sku_name
    capacity = var.sku.capacity
    tier     = var.sku.tier
    family   = contains(local.vcore_tiers, var.sku.tier) ? local.elastic_pool_vcore_family : null
  } : null

}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
  name = "ansumantest"
}
resource "azurerm_sql_server" "server" {
  name = "ansumansqlserver"

  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.test.name

  version                      = var.server_version
  administrator_login          = var.administrator_login
  administrator_login_password = var.administrator_password
}
resource "azurerm_mssql_elasticpool" "elastic_pool" {
  name  = "ansumansqlelastic-pool"

  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.test.name

  server_name = azurerm_sql_server.server.name

  per_database_settings {
    max_capacity = coalesce(var.database_max_capacity, var.sku.capacity)
    min_capacity = var.database_min_capacity
  }

  max_size_gb    = var.elastic_pool_max_size
  zone_redundant = var.zone_redundant

  sku {
    capacity = local.elastic_pool_sku.capacity
    name     = local.elastic_pool_sku.name
    tier     = local.elastic_pool_sku.tier
    family   = local.elastic_pool_sku.family
  }
}
```

***variable.tf***

```
variable "server_version" {
  description = "Version of the SQL Server. Valid values are: 2.0 (for v11 server) and 12.0 (for v12 server). See https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/sql_server.html#version"
  type        = string
  default     = "12.0"
}

variable "administrator_login" {
  description = "Administrator login for SQL Server"
  type        = string
  default = "ansumanadmin"
}

variable "administrator_password" {
  description = "Administrator password for SQL Server"
  type        = string
  default = "Password@1234"
}

variable "elastic_pool_max_size" {
  description = "Maximum size of the Elastic Pool in gigabytes"
  type        = string
  default     = 756
}

variable "sku" {
  description = <<DESC
    SKU for the Elastic Pool with tier and eDTUs capacity. Premium tier with zone redundancy is mandatory for high availability.
    Possible values for tier are "GP_Gen5", "BC_Gen5" for vCore models and "Basic", "Standard", or "Premium" for DTU based models. Example {tier="Standard", capacity="50"}.
    See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-dtu-resource-limits-elastic-pools"
DESC

  type = object({
    tier     = string,
    capacity = number,
  })
}

variable "zone_redundant" {
  description = "Whether or not the Elastic Pool is zone redundant, SKU tier must be Premium to use it. This is mandatory for high availability."
  type        = bool
  default     = false
}

variable "database_min_capacity" {
  description = "The minimum capacity (DTU or vCore) all databases are guaranteed in the Elastic Pool. Defaults to 0."
  type        = string
  default     = "0"
}

variable "database_max_capacity" {
  description = "The maximum capacity (DTU or vCore) any one database can consume in the Elastic Pool. Default to the max Elastic Pool capacity."
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}
```

**Output:**

***If we provide `{tier="Standard",capacity=50}` for the variable value then we get the below output:***

[image]

***If we provide `{tier="GeneralPurpose",capacity=40}` for the variable value then we get the below output:***

[image]